# How to get temperature value on javascript (serverside)?

Tags: javascript, api

I was looking to use a weather API (like yahoo's) and make my javascript code able to return the temperature given a city.
My app runs on rivescript (built on javascript and node).

Researching I only found ways to do it locally on json, or by using html and css as well, but I just want a simple javascript code that returns a value with the temperature.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is really hard to understand. When writing an API you usually return JSON or XML. On the client side you ask for the data using JavaScript (web) or any other language (native). If you want to parse JSON given by an API, you load it and read values from it. In case of JSON you don't even need any special unmarshalling in JS.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this, using [openweathermap.org](http://openweathermap.org/) APIs:

```
function getWeather(city, callback) {
  var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';
  $.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: url,
    jsonCallback: 'jsonp',
    data: { q: city },
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
      callback(data.main.temp);
    }
  });
}
```

This example uses a name of a city as input, and returns temperature in K° degrees.
The `data.main.temp` value is returned, but you could return just `data` to have the whole weather object for that city.

Otherwise, if you want to use Yahoo Weather API (with your APPID):

```
function getWeather(position, callback) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;

    // Yahoo's PlaceFinder API http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/
    // We are passing the R gflag for reverse geocoding (coordinates to place name)
    var geoAPI = 'http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?location='+lat+','+lon+'&flags=J&gflags=R&appid='+APPID;

    // Forming the query for Yahoo's weather forecasting API with YQL
    // http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/
    var wsql = 'select * from weather.forecast where woeid=WID and u="'+DEG+'"',
    weatherYQL = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q='+encodeURIComponent(wsql)+'&format=json&callback=?', code, city, results, woeid;

    // Issue a cross-domain AJAX request (CORS) to the GEO service (not supported in Opera and IE)
    $.getJSON(geoAPI, function(r) {
        if (r.ResultSet.Found == 1) {
            results = r.ResultSet.Results;
            city = results[0].city;
            code = results[0].statecode || results[0].countrycode; 
            woeid = results[0].woeid; // the the city identifier for the weather API

            // Make a weather API request (it is JSONP, so CORS is not an issue):
            $.getJSON(weatherYQL.replace('WID', woeid), function(r) {
                if (r.query.count == 1) {
                    var item = r.query.results.channel.item.condition;
                    callback(item.temp
                } else {
                    console.error("Error retrieving weather data!");
                }
            });
        }
    }).error(function(){
        console.error("Sorry, your browser does not support CORS requests!");
    });
}
```

This example uses a `position` as input (see `navigator.geolocation`), and returns temperature in C° degrees.

*Note:*

*- both examples imply the use of jQuery.*

*- the second example implies having obtained a Yahoo APPID*